# Java equals does not working correctly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I don't understand why this throw me an error, both objects are equals, what can be happening?
I think, there is something wrong with the Pet collection, because if i delete it, all works fine.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: org.company.petshop.domains.Person<Person [id=10, dni=3547249, email=jdoe@mail.com, firstName=John, lastName=Doe, username=johndoe, password=johndoe, role=USER_ROLE, status=Active, pets=[]]> 
but was: org.company.petshop.domains.Person<Person [id=10, dni=3547249, email=jdoe@mail.com, firstName=John, lastName=Doe, username=johndoe, password=johndoe, role=USER_ROLE, status=Active, pets=[]]>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at org.company.petshop.services.PersonServicesTests.testPersonShouldBeSaved(PersonServicesTests.java:24)
```

the unit test is:

```
public class PersonServicesTests {

    @Autowired
    private IGenericService<Person> personService;

    @Test
    public void testPersonShouldBeSaved() {
        Person p = new Person(3547249, "jdoe@mail.com", "John", "Doe", "johndoe", "johndoe", "USER_ROLE");
        personService.create(p);

        assertEquals(p, personService.findById(10));
    }
}
```

the equals method:

```
 @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (this == obj)
          return true;
      if (obj == null)
          return false;
      if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
          return false;
      Person other = (Person) obj;
      if (dni == null) {
          if (other.dni != null)
              return false;
      } else if (!dni.equals(other.dni))
          return false;
      if (email == null) {
          if (other.email != null)
              return false;
      } else if (!email.equals(other.email))
          return false;
      if (firstName == null) {
          if (other.firstName != null)
              return false;
      } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
          return false;
      if (id == null) {
          if (other.id != null)
              return false;
      } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
          return false;
      if (lastName == null) {
          if (other.lastName != null)
              return false;
      } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
          return false;
      if (password == null) {
          if (other.password != null)
              return false;
      } else if (!password.equals(other.password))
          return false;
      if (role == null) {
          if (other.role != null)
              return false;
      } else if (!role.equals(other.role))
          return false;
      if (status == null) {
          if (other.status != null)
              return false;
      } else if (!status.equals(other.status))
          return false;
      if (tasks == null) {
          if (other.tasks != null)
              return false;
      } else if (!tasks.equals(other.tasks))
          return false;
      if (username == null) {
          if (other.username != null)
              return false;
      } else if (!username.equals(other.username))
          return false;
      return true;
  }
```

Comment: I bet on an `equals` methods you're delegating to that is not implemented (the right way).

Comment: Should i implement equals without the pets collection? because in that case all works good!

Comment: The only field not shown in the stack dump is tasks. What is shown if this is included in toString()?

Comment: Are you using the equals-Method of an array or collection? Then that are the equals methods you're delegating to which is not right. They only check for object identity and not same content.

Comment: 2 things I see which can be wrong, first the class check. Hibernate can generate a proxy for your person which could lead to a Person not being a Person but a Person$EnhancedByCglib$2 or something like that. Next you are doing a `tasks.equals(other.tasks)` that will fail for collections, you will have to compare the content of that collection and make sure the elements in the collection have proper equals methods as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67496/discussion-on-question-by-dring-dring-java-equals-does-not-working-correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the built in `equals` for this kind of test is a bad idea for a couple of reasons:

1. As you can see here, a test failure doesn't give you the diagnostics that you want to actually figure out why the objects are different
2. If you're implementing `equals` purely for the test, if it changes later on (usually for a business reason) then your test might be passing now but it shouldn't
3. You need to keep the `equals` method up to date as you add/remove fields.

I can recommend using the `sameBeanAs` method that we wrote that will do a reflective deep object comparison and provide you good diagnostics at the same time.  You can use it like this:

```
assertThat(p, sameBeanAs(personService.findById(10)));
```

See [here](http://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest) for information on how to use and access it